# Quick way to generate an array of hashes in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to build an array of folders with the files contained in each. So if your directory structure is:

```
DirA
  |- FileA
  \- FileB
DirB
  \- FileC
```

And I'm given this array:

```
files = ["DirA/FileA", "DirA/FileB", "DirB/FileC"]
```

I'm trying to build a hash like this

```
{DirA => [FileA, FileB], DirB => [FileC]}
```

Right now I'm doing it in what I think is a fairly non-Rubyish way (assume String has a method defined which fetches the parent directory):

```
h = {}
files.each do |f|
    parent = f.getParentDir
    if not h[parent] then h[parent] = [] end
    h[parent].push f
end
```

Is there are more elegant way?

Comment: You only care about files directly contained in directories, not nested files/directories?

Comment: I'm using a list of files provided to me, and I'm interested in referring to them by their parent directories so I can check they all exist.

Comment: `if not h[parent] then h[parent] = [] end` can be replaced with 
`h[parent] = [] unless h[parent]` or the even rubier `h[parent] ||= []`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do

```
h = {}
files.each do |f|
    (h[f.getParentDir] ||= []) << f
end
```

Comment: Nice. Lots more good answers but this was the shortest, and it uses the method I had defined on String. In my actual use case `getParentPath` is a method I define on `NSURL` but I was trying to simplify things for you guys. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick:

```
result = files.group_by { |i| i.split("/").first }
result.each_key { |k| result[k] = result[k].map { |f| f.split("/").last } }
```

If you're into brevity, you can replace the second line with

```
result.merge!(result) { |k, v| v.map { |f| f.split("/").last } }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this hash (with array)

```
{DirA => [FileA, FileB], DirB => [FileC]}

files.each_with_object(Hash.new{|h,k|h[k]=[]}) do |m,res|
  k,v = m.split('/')
  res[k] << v
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
files = ["DirA/FileA", "DirA/FileB", "DirB/FileC"]

files.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |path, hash|
  parent, file = path.split('/', 2)
  hash[parent] << file
end

#=> {"DirA"=>["FileA", "FileB"], "DirB"=>["FileC"]}
```